# Is this Transaction valid?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am wondering if this transaction is even valid and actually ensuring quantity is being the most up to date.

```
async function deductQuantity(orders: [Order]) : Promise<boolean> {
  try {
    let document = await admin.firestore().collection("MenuItems")
   
       orders.forEach(async (order)=> {
        let itemDoc = (await document.where(`item.catalogType`, "==", order.catalogType).where(`item.id`, "==", order.item.id))
        let get = await itemDoc.get()
        get.forEach(async a=> {
          const pp = document.doc(a.id)
      
            await admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (t)=> { 
              const mostRecentDoc = await t.get(pp)
    
               const data = await mostRecentDoc.data()
              if (data == undefined){
                return
              }
              const newQuantity = data.item.quantity - order.quantity
              await t.update(pp, {[`item.quantity`] : newQuantity})
            })
          
        })
       
        
       
      })
      return true
  } catch (error) {

    console.log("dum: " + error)
    return false
  }

  
}
```

the part where I do let get = await itemDoc.get(), and get.ForEach, is kind of unnecessary because I know, that it will only return one document that matches the query field, but I need to forEach it in order to get the child component\s. Anyways, is it a valid transaction?

Comment: It's valid if it works the way you want.  If it doesn't work the way you expect, you should edit the question to state clearly what's not working - what is it doing other than what you expect?

Comment: @DougStevenson well I don't really have a way to test transactions

Comment: Sure you do - run the code.